# IE (10&11): show css (or even gif) animation while loading base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

all.

I have a really strange bug, on which i spent a lot of time and haven't solved yet...

I have this fiddle:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ctuvyom1VEuff6yD3gls?p=preview

```
    $scope.photoChanged = function(files) {
    $scope.files = files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $scope.imagecontent = e.target.result;
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  };
```

and in chrome, ff, opera, safari - when i upload image to browser until it is displayed i see css animation

**but!**

in ie 10/11 i see that browser window is busy, and css animation is busy to: no animation. also i try to set gif animation: but still huge base64 image took all resources

maybe anybody could give advice how to be, and in which side to see? really, i'm confused, i didn't know how to solve it((  loader is stoppped (paused) in ie.

also images, which i try to upload to browser:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/Victory-squarepngpngpng.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/19af71228a66376d950e32cc065ff250.png